# Difference between the returned values of two selector functions in this code

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, igrouping

```
var Students = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Students.Add( "Bob" , 60);
Students.Add( "Jim" , 62);
Students.Add( "Jack", 75);
Students.Add( "John", 81);
Students.Add( "Matt", 60);
Students.Add( "Jill", 72);
Students.Add( "Eric", 83);
Students.Add( "Adam", 60);
Students.Add( "Gary", 75);

var MyVar  = Students.GroupBy(r=> r.Value)
                     .ToDictionary(t=> t.Key, t=> t.Select(x=> x.Key));
```

The `Students` object has `Name` and `Weight` key-value pairs.

In the ToDictionary method, `t` variable is of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<K, T>>`. That is, `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Students>>`

Why are the `Key` values returned by `t=>t.Key` and `t=> t.Select(**x=> x.Key**)` different? They both use the same `t` variable. `Key` should be of type `int`.

The image was taken after the GroupBy method had been executed.(It is not the full image) One of the `Key` has the value of `60` and the other one has the values of `Bob`, `Matt` and `Adam`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's not a

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Student>>
```

It's a

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, KeyValuePair<int, Student>>>
```

In `t => t.Key` you're referring to the grouping key, and in `Select(x => x.Key)` you're referring to the `KeyValuePair`.

You can hover over the variables in Visual Studio to see the types and the type parameters.

**In more detail:**

```
// return an IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, KeyValuePair<int, Student>>>
Students.GroupBy(r=> r.Value)
// iterate over each IGrouping<int, KeyValuePair<int, Student>>
    .ToDictionary(
        group => group.Key,
// iterate over each KeyValuePair<int, Student> in the group
// because IGrouping<TKey, TElement> inherits from IEnumerable<TElement>
// so it's a Select over an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Student>>
        group => group.Select(pair => pair.Key));
```

Comment: same question: why does `Select(x => x.Key)` refer to the `KeyValuePair`returned by `GroupBy`?

Answer (score 2):

It is creating a new dictionary with number as Key and all the student names from original dictionary related to particular key.

Here is how it works.

> Why are the Key values returned by `t=>t.Key`

That is operating over the `GroupBy`, since `GroupBy` is applied on `Value`, which is `int` in the original dictionary. Thus the new dictionary would have the distinct keys based on original dictionary's values.

> and t=> t.Select(**x=> x.Key**) different?

Now this `Select` is operating on each `GroupBy` item from original dictionary. Where `Key` is the student name. Thus getting all the student names based on the `Key` selected previously in `GroupBy`

Comment: why does `Select` operate on original dictionary? How does `Select` decide this?

Comment: @user3467437, `Select` operates on each item of `GroupBy`, Which has `Key` as Value from original dictionary and `Values` as collection of related keys from Original dictionary

Answer (score 1):

This is what the result of `Students.GroupBy(r => r.Value)` looks like. It's a bit confusing, since both `GroupBy` as well as `Dictionary` use a `Key`.

```
    { (Key = 60, {(Key = "Bob", Value = 60), (Key = "Matt", Value = 60), ...}),
      (Key = 62, {(Key = "Jim", Value = 62)}),
      (Key = 72. ...),
      ...
    }
```

`t` is one *row* of this grouping.

The first selector `t.Key` yields `60`.

The second selector `t.Select(x => x.Key)` operates on the *list* and yields `{"Bob", "Matt", "Adam"}`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Key` of the `IGrouping` (`t.Key`) is the key that you grouped on in `GroupBy`.  In this case this is the `Value` of the `KeyValuePair`.

The Key within the `Select` (`x.Key`) is getting the key of the `KeyValuePair` for each pair within the group.

It's somewhat less obvious here due to the inferred types, but you can hover over both `x` and `t` in visual studio to see that `t` is an `IGrouping` and `x` is a `KeyValuePair`.  You could also improve the clarity of this query (quite a bit, in my mind) by using more meaningful variable names.

```
var MyVar = Students.GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)
                        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key,
                        group => group.Select(pair => pair.Key));
```